# Template path instead of it self in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular ui-Router and ui-View to serve them in the app. This is my routes index:

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });    

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '',
            template: require('./pages/generic/generic.html'),
            data: {
                public: true
            },
        })
        .state('app.main', {
            url: '/',
            template: require('./pages/main/main.html'),
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'Ctrl'
        });
...
```

Instead of template it self i see path to it. Also when i'm using `templateUrl` i have `Cannot GET /template-file-path` for the template file. Why is it happending? I'm using webpack with webpack server. Thx for help.

Comment: try adding Absolute path of html file

Comment: alternative path will cross with node_modules path

Comment: on which path does your webpack server serves your application?

Comment: ```output: { path: _path + '/dist', publicPath: '/' },```

Comment: use templateUrl : './pages/generic/generic.html',

Answer (score 0):

If your application's file structure is like

```
myDemoAppName -> app -> pages -> main -> main.html
```

and your server serves your files on `myDemoAppName` path

You should use `templateUrl: '/app/pages/main/main.html'`

Comment: I've wrote this abbove that whan i'm using `templateUrl` i have `Cannot GET /src/app/pages/generic/generic.html` :(

Comment: so you serve your files at "x location" which is the parent of  "src" path?

Comment: `bit.ly/2nE1S1B` this is the structure, inside is pages directory

Comment: try /app/pages/generic/generic.html maybe it helps

Comment: tried everything, all is wrong `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /app/pages/generic/generic.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)`